# levels function alternative for data table R

Tags: r, data.table, levels

If I'm not mistaken, the levels function doesn't apply to a data table (correct me if wrong, i'm new to R)

```
> levels(DT$C1)
NULL
```

Is there an alternative for a data table? I'm not finding anything usefull.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of the levels of a certain column of my data table

Comment: I'm sorry, that was the command I tried, I posted the wrong code (one of the other thing I tried that didn't work)

Comment: `DT$C1` is not a `data.table`- it's a vector. So if this vector is of class `factor`- `levels(DT$C1)` will work. In your case it seem not to be the case.

Comment: Thanks! I used as.factor on my column (vector) and now it works! And I understand that it indeed is a vector that i'm using as an argument. Feeling kinda stupid that the answer is so easy

Answer (score 4):

Just use unique. Levels doesn't work unless you change the column type to factor

```
unique(DT$C1)
```

or

```
DT[,C1:=as.factor(C1)]
levels(DT$C1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't upvote because I'm new here, but this was very usefull!

Comment: NP - here is excellent intro to data.table in R https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro-vignette.html - at the very start it starts talking about (Unlike data.frames, columns of character type are never converted to factors by default.).